# How can I make UrlScan test extensionless urls?

Tags: security, iis, sql, isapi-filters

If I use UrlScan to block common SQL Injection attempts on asp- and aspx-files, I would do something like this:

```
[SQLInjection] 
AppliesTo=.asp,.aspx
DenyDataSection=SQLInjectionStrings 
ScanURL=0 
ScanAllRaw=0 
ScanQueryString=1 
ScanHeaders=
[SQLInjectionStrings] 
-- 
alter 
delete 
(...)
```

That would catch

```
/default.asp?EVILACTION=DELETEDROPSLASHANDBURN
/default.aspx?EVILACTION=DELETEDROPSLASHANDBURN
```

But NOT

```
/?EVILACTION=DELETEDROPSLASHANDBURN
```

How can I make an Urlscan section apply to extensionless urls too?

I tried *.*, leaving it blank etc - no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of leaving it blank, simply omit the `AppliesTo` flag entirely. If you don't have it at all, it should apply to all requests. If you specify it, but leave the value blank, it won't apply to any requests.